# Is there a quick way to tell what are the divisors of $11^{273}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

An exercise its asking me to tell what are the divisors of $11^{273}$.

My first thought was that any prime number raised to any number would be prime but this is not true ($2^2 = 4$ not prime). Since this is a really huge number, what would be the fastest way to solve this exercise? Thank you.

Comment: The divisors of $p^n$  are $p^r,0\le r\le n$ for any prime $p$

Comment: How is this 'abstract algebra'?

Comment: To the OP: Look at some examples of small powers of small  primes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $11$ is prime, $11^{273}$ has $274$ natural divisors:

- $11^0$
- $11^1$
- $\dots$
- $11^{272}$
- $11^{273}$